# SQL how to create a table with a unique key?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

Create a courses table with this definition (try using a multi-line SQL statement):

```
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(3) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title   | varchar(255)        | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| credits | tinyint(2) unsigned | NO   |     | 1       |                |
```

I keep getting an error when trying to create the table, this is what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE courses 
(
    id int(3)  unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    credits tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;
```

Comment: What error occurs? What DB are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Two mistakes:

- The `auto_increment` column must be a primary key in MySQL.
- You need to end the SQL sentence with a `)`.

This SQL works:

```
CREATE TABLE courses (
  id int(3)  unsigned primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  credits tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Error:

`Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

Correct SQL sentence:

```
CREATE TABLE courses (
id      int(3) unsigned   primary key  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title   varchar(255)        NOT NULL UNIQUE,
credits tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1);
```

Your sentence loses `primary key`.